# What's the meaning "No data available(61)" during getxattr system call

Tags: android, kernel, system-calls, cts

Daer all.
I'm facing problem during trying Android CTS(4.4 R3).

the whole of error logs are like below:

```
01-22 17:19:44.844 D/        (22802): isPermittedCapBitSet():     getxattr("/system/bin/run-as") call failed: return -1 (error: No data available (61))
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802): failed: testRunAsHasCorrectCapabilities(android.permission.cts.FileSystemPermissionTest)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802): ----- begin exception -----
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802): 
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802): junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:48)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:27)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at android.permission.cts.FileSystemPermissionTest.testRunAsHasCorrectCapabilities(FileSystemPermissionTest.java:828)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802):         at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
01-22 17:19:44.844 I/TestRunner(22802): ----- end exceptbinder: release 22792:22801 transaction 150222 in, still active
```

I traced what function cause these errors

/cts/tests/tests/permission/jni/android_permission_cts_FileUtils.cpp

```
 95 static jboolean isPermittedCapBitSet(JNIEnv* env, jstring path, size_t capId)
 96 {
 97     const char* pathStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(path, NULL);
 98     jboolean ret = false;
 99 
100     struct vfs_cap_data capData;
101     memset(&capData, 0, sizeof(capData));
102 
103     ssize_t result = getxattr(pathStr, XATTR_NAME_CAPS, &capData,
104                               sizeof(capData));
105     if (result > 0) {
106       ret = (capData.data[CAP_TO_INDEX(capId)].permitted &
107              CAP_TO_MASK(capId)) != 0;
108       ALOGD("isPermittedCapBitSet(): getxattr(\"%s\") call succeeded, "
109             "cap bit %u %s",
110             pathStr, capId, ret ? "set" : "unset");
111     } else {
112       ALOGD("isPermittedCapBitSet(): getxattr(\"%s\") call failed: "
113             "return %d (error: %s (%d))\n",
114             pathStr, result, strerror(errno), errno);
115     }
116 
117     env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(path, pathStr);
118     return ret;
119 }
120
```

The error made by getxattr().

I don't know what should I do.
I already checked /system/bin/run-as. It exists and has connect permission and ownership

```
root@123:/ # ls -al /system/bin/run-as                                     
-rwxr-x--- root     shell        9500 2015-01-21 14:54 run-as
```

Please let me teach what should I check ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to recompile your kernel with eXtended ATTRibutes (xattr) enabled. For the ext3 filesystem, the config value in `.config` is:

`CONFIG_EXT3_FS_XATTR`

But, in your linux source tree, type

`make menuconfig`

and use that interface to enable extended attributes for the file system(s) you are using. Then recompile your kernel after that.